# Blank Highcharts div fixed by a reboot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm using highcharts v4.2.3 via (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js) and doing development on an OSX v10.11 computer running rails v5.0.0.beta3.  Normally my graphs work without issue.  But on occasion the divs become blank without any cause that I can detect.  I've tried halting and restarting the rails server but that doesn't fix it.  Additionally, no errors are reported in the javascript console.  The only way I can fix it is to restart my entire computer.  Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: When they are blank are there any errors in the javascript console in the browser? Any other errors reported?

Comment: Have you tried to monitor your memory usage? Maybe this is the reason, that any memory leak exists ?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I found it had to do with Chrome.  When I restarted Chrome the graphs worked again.